# arrayList i only show the last element

Tags: arraylist

I have the following problem. I'm trying to show all the elements of a display arrayList but I can only see the last item repeated as many times as there are number of elements in the ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class PurebaArrayList {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<PuntoDouble> puntos = new ArrayList<>();

    PuntoDouble p = new PuntoDouble();

    for(int cont = 0; cont< 100; cont++){
        p.setX(cont);
        p.setY(cont);
        puntos.add(p);            
    }
    System.out.println(puntos.toString());
}
}



public class PuntoDouble{

private double x;
private double y;

public PuntoDouble(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public PuntoDouble(){

}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PuntoDouble{" + "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + '}';
}   
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `PuntoDouble` for every entry you add to the list. At the moment you add just a single instance of a `PuntoDouble` which you modify.
Therefore change the code to:

```
for(int cont = 0; cont< 100; cont++){
    PuntoDouble p = new PuntoDouble();
    p.setX(cont);
    p.setY(cont);
    puntos.add(p);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are, *literally*, adding the same `PuntoDouble` as each of the 100 elements of the array.  If you want them to be distinct from each other, you need to make a `new` one for each.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging,slightly change 100 to 3 and add for each iteration to print out the elements in `puntos`.

```
    // adds to ArrayList
    for(int cont = 0; cont< 10; cont++){
        p.setX(cont);
        p.setY(cont);
        System.out.println("[add]" + p);
        puntos.add(p);
    }

    // iterates ArrayList puntos' elements
    for(PuntoDouble pd : puntos){
        System.out.println("[contain]" + pd);
    }


debug output lines:
[add]PuntoDouble{x=0.0, y=0.0}
[add]PuntoDouble{x=1.0, y=1.0}
[add]PuntoDouble{x=2.0, y=2.0}
[add]PuntoDouble{x=3.0, y= 3.0}
[contain]PuntoDouble{x=9.0, y=9.0}
[contain]PuntoDouble{x=9.0, y=9.0}
[contain]PuntoDouble{x=9.0, y=9.0}
```

What you did is created an `PuntoDouble` object `p` and initilized it by invoking default constructor. In the for loop, the values of `p` modifies, but the reference of `p` never changed, therefore you kept adding the same object into ArrayList 100 times, all of those added objects refer to the same address in memory(`new` an object once before the for loop) which the value x is 99.0 and y is 99.0 (the last added values)

What you should do is creating a new object each iterate.

```
for(int cont = 0; cont< 100; cont++){
        puntos.add(new PuntoDouble(cont, cont));
}
```